# Inserir dados dinamicamente com xml as coordenadas no mapa de calor

Tags: php, javascript, json, xml

Estou tentando usar esse código para ler os dados das coordenadas `xml` ao invés dos dados inserido estaticamente no código porem não funciona quando feito desta forma.
Código:

```
function getPoints() {
  return [
                //new google.maps.LatLng(-26.20478566666, -51.0518355),                 
                //new google.maps.LatLng(-26.265426, -51.10279483333),
                //  new google.maps.LatLng(-26.265426, -51.10279483333),                    
                //  new google.maps.LatLng(-26.22920166666, -51.08537583333),
                //  new google.maps.LatLng(-26.21230783333, -51.0784765),
                //  new google.maps.LatLng(-26.21460016666,-51.07964916666),
                //  new google.maps.LatLng(-26.21396566666, -51.076862),
                //  new google.maps.LatLng(-26.23305616666, -51.05080116666),
                //  new google.maps.LatLng(-26.2335205, -51.05153366666),
                //  new google.maps.LatLng(-26.22982933333, -51.08531783333),
                //  new google.maps.LatLng(-26.20052716666, -51.09534966666),
                //  new google.maps.LatLng(-26.22196833333, -51.05161116666),
                //  new google.maps.LatLng(-26.20052716666, -51.09534966666),
                //  new google.maps.LatLng(-26.22196833333, -51.05161116666),
                //  new google.maps.LatLng(-26.22650916666, -51.08625616666),
                //  new google.maps.LatLng(-26.22650916666, -51.08625616666),
                //  new google.maps.LatLng(-26.22196833333, -51.05161116666),                   
                //  new google.maps.LatLng(-26.22650916666, -51.08625616666)

                    downloadUrl("dados.xml", function(data) 
                    {
                        var xml = data.responseXML;
                        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
                        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) 
                        {                     
                             var point = new google.maps.LatLng
                             (
                              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng"))
                              );                    
                        };              
                    }
                    );
  ];
}
function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
              var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
                  new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
                  new XMLHttpRequest;

              request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4) {
                  request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
                  callback(request, request.status);
                }
              };

              request.open('GET', url, true);
              request.send(null);
```

A implementação que estou usando é baseado neste exemplo https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer?hl=pt-br#load_the_visualization_library

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo do que tem esse `dados.xml`?

Comment: Resolveu sua duvida?